# Php application is too slow when using haproxy

Tags: haproxy

In my php application when I use mysql direct connection it work perfectly. But when I use haproxy ip for ha, it's taking too long to retrieve result.

Ha proxy configuration as following

```
   global
        maxconn         5000
        nbproc          5

defaults
    retries 3
    option  redispatch
    timeout client 120s
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout server 120s

frontend galera_cluster_frontend
    bind 0.0.0.0:3307
    mode tcp

    log global
    option  dontlognull

    option tcplog
    default_backend galera_cluster_backend


backend galera_cluster_backend

     mode tcp
     option tcpka

    option tcplog
    option log-health-checks
    retries                   3
    balance leastconn
    server db-server-01 e2e-34-201:3306  check weight 1
    server db-server-02 e2e-34-202:3306  check weight 3
    server db-server-03 e2e-34-203:3306  check weight 2
```

Comment: what do you see in the haproxy logs for the 'long' runtime. I suggest to remove the `option tcpka`.

Comment: ok let me check and inform you